# How to remove/desolder very minute smd chips safely?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, soldering, surface-mount

This is the component I'm trying to remove: BU48xx voltage detector VSOF package (attached pic)[image]

Comment: Hot air tool of course. This is surely a duplicate of several existing questions.

Comment: If you have no hot air, 2 soldering irons might also work, the component might not survive though. Hot air and **experience how to use that** are the best option though.

Comment: Another "trick" is using a very big solder iron tip and putting lots of solder on it. Then you can use that "solder drop" to heat all pins and the component simultaneously. Sometimes it will just come off, but maybe you have to push it slightly to the side. However, this is likely to damage the component because of excessive heating.

Comment: You could use a tip designed for the purpose. https://www.paceworldwide.com/products/tips-and-nozzles/soldering-iron-tips/ps90-tips/ps90-surfacemount-and-thermobond-tips/sot23-removal-tip-304

Comment: [You do it as described here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417253/desoldering-soldering-1-4-chip-with-eight-pins/417270#417270)  That gives a step by step description of removing and replacing an 8 pin SMD part.  It'll work just as well for your problem, but heat the side with 4 pins first, and then heat the side with two pins and pull the part out.  The four pin side first because the larger volume of solder on that side will stay hot (and liquid) longer.